# PayPal Single Payout to an Email

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to integrate PayPal's Payout option to be able to pay users directly by providing their email.

I am calling the controller function through a form with POST method, after I call the simplePay function, all I get is a blank page, I would like to know if what I'm doing is correct, incomplete (and what its lacking), or wrong (and what am I doing wrong).

I've based my research on code samples provided by Paypal Documentation.
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payouts/CreateBatchPayout.php

Route:

```
Route::post('/simplePay', 'PaypalController@simplePay');
```

Controller:

```
    <?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
    use PayPal\Api\Amount;
    use PayPal\Api\Details;
    use PayPal\Api\Item;
    use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
    use PayPal\Api\Payer;
    use PayPal\Api\Payment;
    use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
    use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
    use PayPal\Api\ExecutePayment;
    use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
    use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

    class PaypalController extends Controller
    {

      private $_api_context;
        public function __construct()
        {
            // setup PayPal api context
            $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
            $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_conf['client_id'], $paypal_conf['secret']));
            $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
        }
        public function simplePay()
        {
            $payouts = new \PayPal\Api\Payout();
            $senderBatchHeader = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutSenderBatchHeader();
            $senderBatchHeader->setSenderBatchId(uniqid())->setEmailSubject("You have a Payout!");
            $senderItem = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem();
            $senderItem->setRecipientType('Email')->setNote('Thanks for your patronage!')->setReceiver('email@gmail.com')->setSenderItemId("001")->setAmount(new \PayPal\Api\Currency('{
                                    "value":"1.00",
                                    "currency":"MXN"
                                }'));
            $payouts->setSenderBatchHeader($senderBatchHeader)->addItem($senderItem);
            $request = clone $payouts;
            try {
                $output = $payouts->createSynchronous($this->_api_context);
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                //  \ResultPrinter::printError("Created Single Synchronous Payout", "Payout", null, $request, $ex);
                exit(1);
            }
            // \ResultPrinter::printResult("Created Single Synchronous Payout", "Payout", $output->getBatchHeader()->getPayoutBatchId(), $request, $output);
            return $output;
        }
    }
```

Call to controller:

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{{ url('/simplePay') }}">
                        {{csrf_field()}}

                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pay">
                        </form>

                    </div>
```

paypal.php - app/config file - Just in Case:

```
<?php
return array(
    // set your paypal credential
    'client_id' => 'AXs...',
    'secret' => 'AHE...',

    /**
     * SDK configuration
     */
    'settings' => array(
        /**
         * Available option 'sandbox' or 'live'
         */
        'mode' => 'sandbox',

        /**
         * Specify the max request time in seconds
         */
        'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 12000,

        /**
         * Whether want to log to a file
         */
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,

        /**
         * Specify the file that want to write on
         */
        'log.FileName' => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal.log',

        /**
         * Available option 'FINE', 'INFO', 'WARN' or 'ERROR'
         *
         * Logging is most verbose in the 'FINE' level and decreases as you
         * proceed towards ERROR
         */
        'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
    ),
);
```

Comment: Your code is terminating execution when an error is thrown which is why you're seeing a blank page, you should replace `exit(1);` with something like `dd($ex);` and then debug from there. We won't be able to help you with such a general question, you need to follow basic debugging yourself and then update your question with specifics.

Comment: okidoki let me try debugging and will be posting any further doubts! thanks for the advice.

Comment: This was the error: SYNC_MODE_NOT_APPLICABLE - "message":"Synchronous mode will soon be deprecated and is no longer available for new integrations. You can use the asynchronous mode by specifying sync_mode= false in the request."                                                                                     
"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors" Solved by editing sync mode on /vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Payout.php :) Thanks SAM!

Comment: @ChristianPérezCadavid thank you for this follow up, you just helped me out!

Answer (score 3):

PayPal sync mode is not available for new integrations. Existing integrations will continue to function if your passing `"sync_mode = true"`.

To solve the issue, you need to pass `"sync_mode = false"` so instead of

```
$output = $payouts->createSynchronous($this->_api_context);
```

use the following:

```
$output = $payouts->create(array('sync_mode' => 'false'), $this->_api_context);
```